# I want to change text color of cells in excel with macros

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I have a macros that copied last cell value of group cells in a vertical column, e.g.,

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT ( added one extra line), here it is:

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next
    Cells(N + 1, "A").FillDown
End Sub
```

Please add one more function in this macro. I want to change the the text color of that cell which is copied with red, something like to add:

```
'change formatting to your liking:

formulaCell.Font.Bold = True
formulaCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

I was forget to ask this in previous my previous question.

Comment: Perhaps `Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N + 1, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`.

Comment: It could not fill the last cell with red color, even it skip to copy the last cell of grouped cells.

Comment: i am sorry but I simply do noy understand. PERHAPS YOU COULD START A NEW QUESTION,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the cell(s) that have been filled down then add the formatting changes to **rr** as you progress through the loop.

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each rr In r
        with rr
            .FillDown
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        end with
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added one more line, after that it is not working. Here it is:
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each rr In r
        rr.FillDown
    Next

    Cells(N + 1, "A").FillDown
End Sub

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to fill below the last row or is column A habitually one value short of the other columns?

Comment: I have added that EDIT in question. I can't able to make this code properly , since stackoverflow remove breaks.